# IntelliJ IDEA quick quoted string plus variable

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA has completion features which, besides increasing coding speed, maintain the "flow" of coding (always moving forward); so I wonder whether I'm missing something when I encounter a situation like the following (simplified):

```
System.out.println("The name of the user is " + userName);
```

After auto-completing System.out.println, as I am typing "The name of...", IDEA has already generated the two double quotations and has me between them. Now if I want to include a variable with this string, I currently use the right arrow key to move cursor after the second quotation mark to type + userName. Please assume that I have to include variables with strings like that repetitively, or hundreds of times in a relatively short time, for different strings or phrases.

So my question is: Is there a way for me to avoid having to take my right hand off touch-typing position, take my eyes off the screen to look at the arrows and press the right arrow, before getting back to touch-typing? A shortcut or something I can customize that allows me to just jump out of the string between quotation marks and start typing + variable?

It may seem trivial when done once, but as I mentioned, the use of the arrows breaks the flow for me when I have to do it repetitively. Thanks for any tips and help.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly: Just type the ending double quote even tho it was already generated and then continue with + and variable name.

Comment: Thank you for this tip, Quintium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quintium correctly pointed out that you can "type out of" the quotes by pressing `"`.

Let me show you another solution, using a *Live Template*.

Inside a valid code block (e.g. `main` method...) where your variable `userName` is in scope, type the following

`soutv`

Now press **Tab** and you will see the following

[image: Live Template. soutv]

From here it's easy to select `userName` as the variable.

If you do this very often you can make your own live templates.

In any case it also saves a lot of time to use the `sout` live template to quickly get `System.out.println()`

Comment: Man, that blew my mind away! I had to add an extra tweak due to default settings. Using the tip you gave me about Live Templates, I went to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Live Templates -> output -> soutv -> Edit Variables, and instead of EXPR_COPY having "Skip if defined" ticked, I unticked it. And now soutv is giving me the exact behavior I want, allowing me to type the variable then it jumps to the string within quotations, then I can Ctrl+Shift+Enter to finish the sentence. Comparing this experience with my previous one is just awe-inspiring. Thank you so much!

Comment: And typing the quotation (or overwriting it) works for other situations, too!

Comment: No worries :) Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have arrows mapped to Ctrl+something. Specifically, Ctrl+F - right (Forward) , and Ctrl+B - left (backward).
You could you Ctrl+F for your case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).